# SQL Server Merge 2 columns in a table into 1 column in another

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables containing location-based data.

Table1 has PlaceName, County, Latitude and Longitude (4 columns).

Table2 has PlaceName, County and LatLng (3 columns).

I want to pull the Latitude and Longitude data from Table1 split them with a comma and insert into the LatLng column in Table2 where the PlaceName and County matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple `JOIN` and `concat` would do the trick

```
Update A
   set LatLng = concat(B.Latitude,',',B.Longitude)
 From  Table2 A
 Join  Table1 B 
   on  A.PlaceName=B.PlaceName and A.Country = B.Country
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables for the UPDATE:

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.LatLng = t1.Latitude + ',' + t1.Longtitude 
FROM Table2 AS t2 INNER Table1 AS t1
ON t2.PlaceName = t1.PlaceName AND t2.County = t1.County
```